# Where in the file and how do I submit a form using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I bought a template online and i'm trying to develop a website and I'm stuck on the contact form.  I can't seem to get it to submit.  When I click submit it just remains static, but i'd like to get it to run the action- that is go to the contactTq.php page.  Below is all the code i think you need.  but if you want the entire .js file it's here: http://pastebin.com/1B1j9pkB

```
,submitFu:function(){
_.validateFu(_.labels)                          
if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:_.mailHandlerURL,
        data:{
            name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
            email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
            phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
            //fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
            //state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
            message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
            owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
            stripHTML:_.stripHTML
        },
        success: function(){
            _.showFu()
        }
    })          
},
showFu:function(){
_.success.slideDown(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        _.success.slideUp()
        _.form.trigger('reset')
    },_.successShow)
})
},
```

Here is the form im using:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="contactTq.php" method="post">
<div class="success"> Contact form submitted! <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong></div>
<fieldset>
    <label class="name">
        <input type="text" value="Enter Your Name:">
        <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span>
        <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
        <span class="clear"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="email">
        <input type="text" value="Enter Your E-mail:">
        <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span>
        <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
        <span class="clear"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="phone">
        <input type="text" value="Enter Your Phone (optional):">
        <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span>
        <span class="clear"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="message">
        <textarea>Enter Your Message:</textarea>
        <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span>
        <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
        <span class="clear"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="buttons"><strong><a class="button" data-type="reset">Reset<span></span></a></strong><strong><a class="button" data-type="submit">Submit<span></span></a></strong></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

If you need any other info, please let me know.  Would appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no error callback. Add one. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/ I bet that is being triggered.

Comment: I don't see the closing </form> tag anywhere?

Comment: Another common thing I see with some templates is needing to set data-ajax="false" within the <form> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'll change my comment to an answer.

You're missing the closing FORM tag. Failing that being the cause, sometimes data-ajax="false" within the FORM tag does the trick with some templates.

Comment: so sorry bobster.. i dunno why i missed tht out when i copied and pasted it here.. i do have a closing </form> tag.. anything else u think it could be?